# How to get geometry of clicked feature?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

From [Mapbox's documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api#map#queryrenderedfeatures), I should get a GeoJson feature object when I call *queryRenderedFeatures* method.

I run it from a click event without any filter:

```
this.map.on("click",
    function(e) {
        var clickedCluster
        this.map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point).forEach(function(element) {
            console.log(elem)
        })
    })
```

On my console (see screenshot below), I got feature's properties of the point I click on the map, I got layer's information, but I don't get its geometry. How can I get it?

As far as I understand Mapbox's example, I should obtain it
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures/

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right that `queryRenderedFeatures` returns a GeoJSON [Feature Object](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.2). You may access it's [Geometry Object](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1) like in the following example (for the first feature in *features*):

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point);
    console.log(features[0].geometry) 
});
```

https://jsbin.com/jixiferoya/edit?html,output

Please note (from the [docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#queryrenderedfeatures)):

> Because features come from tiled vector data or GeoJSON data that is
> converted to tiles internally, feature geometries may be split or
> duplicated across tile boundaries [...]

Comment: Oh I test it and it works, I shouldn't trust the javascript console, I thought it content was exhaustive. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

A few additional notes of caution when using **queryRenderedFeatures()**.

Here's the object returned, which contains a bunch of non-standard "GeoJSON [Feature Object](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.2)" properties:

```
{
  _geometry:{type: 'Point', coordinates: Array(2)}
  _vectorTileFeature:Au {properties: {…}, extent: 8192, type: 1, _pbf: xc, 
  _geometry: 164, …}
  id:undefined
  layer:{id: 'markers-layer-public', 
    type: 'symbol', source: 'markers- 
    source-public', layout: {…}, paint: {…}}
    properties:{isMarker: true, name: 'Point Wilson', icon: 'coastpilot', 
    access: 'public', id: 'GNIS1507543'}
  source:'markers-source-public'
  state:{}
  type:'Feature'
  geometry (get):ƒ geometry(){return void 0===this._geometry&&(this._geometry=this._vectorTileFeature.toGeoJSON(this._vectorTileFeature._x,this._vectorTileFeature._y,this._vectorTileFeature._z).geometry),this._geometry}
  geometry (set):ƒ geometry(t){this._geometry=t;}
}
```

Note the get/set methods for **.geometry**. This means a simple copy will fail, ie. you can't use:

```
const featureCopy = {...feature} // this won't copy the geometry!
```

Instead use:

```
const featureCopy = {
  type: feature.type, 
  layer: {...feature.layer}, // if you need this
  properties: {...feature.properties}, 
  geometry: {...feature.geometry}
};
```

Also, note that the **.id** property is undefined.  I'm not sure if this is related to using mapboxgl Draw, but the **.id** property isn't correctly returned even if it was set when the feature was added to the map.

Comment: Thanks this was super helpful